# Open connected sets with connected boundary

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $U$ be a open connected set with connected boundary $\partial U$. Is it true that $\partial U$ is necessarily pathwise connected?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Uh... Your title is completely different from your question.

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I started typing a different question before and I managed to solve it while typing.

Answer (score 2):

How about if $U$ is the complement of the [closed topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: nice example. What changes if we add an assumption: for every $x\in \partial U$ there exists a ball $B=\{y;\|x-y\|<r\}$ such that set $\partial U\cap B$ is connected ?